# 503 - Service Unavailable When redirect to Azure Blob Url from .net core 3.1 Web API

Tags: azure-blob-storage, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

I have written two Web API in .net core 3.1 to redirect the Azure storage blob file url and for download.

**First API** - To redirect to Azure Storage blob url with SAS token.

**Second API** - To return the Azure Storage blob url with SAS token and file downloading logic is handled in client side using the Azure blob url.

These two API works fine on localhost but when hosted in windows server these both API return 503 - Service Unavailable response.

**Note:** 
1. I am using Azure Storage Blobs nugget version of 12.3.0
2. My Blob container is created with Private access.

Let me kindly know what and where I am doing wrongly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you get this 503 Service unavailable?? Does IIS throw this or the call to the blob storage url throw 503 error?

Comment: @theabodeofcode: Thanks for your response. I am getting 503 Service unavailable as response from the API, which will fetch & return or redirect blob storage url. I am not sure whether this error thrown from IIS. Can you kindly let me know how to ensure whether this error thrown from IIS.

Comment: First step would be to check if your client facing API is available of not. Easiest way would be to browse the API and to check if the application pool to which the service is attached is running

Comment: Also have you checked your firewall rules to allow your webapi’s to reach out of the windows server? Any possibility you can capture a fiddler trace of the error, that would tell you what happened.